# Getting multiple query string values with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a url like this:

```
http://example.com/mypage?vendorId=1&vendorId=2&vendorId=3
```

Using jQuery, how can I get every `vendorId` value and put them in an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In javascript, that's just a string:

```
var url = 'http://mysite.com/mypage?vendorId=1&vendorId=2&vendorId=3'
var qs = url.split('?')[1];
var parts = qs.split('&');
var arr = [];

$.each(parts, function() {
    var val = this.split('=')[1];
    arr.push(val);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/49hhW/)

or the short way:

```
var arr = $.map(window.location.split('?')[1].split('&'), function(e,i) { 
    return e.split('=')[1];
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need jQuery for this.

```
var pairs=location.search.slice(1).split('&');
var vendors=[];
for (i in pairs){
    bits=pairs[i].split('=');
    if (bits[0]=='vendorId') vendors.push(bits[1]);
}
```